# Calculating $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$ given that $f(2^{-n})>0$ and $f(3^{-n})<0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function so that $f(2^{-n})>0$ and $f(3^{-n})<0$ for every $n\geq{2}$. Calculate $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$.

I have tried solving it using the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) without any results. How can I solve it?

Comment: Both $(2^{-n})$ and $(3^{-n})$ are sequences that go to zero. What can you get from this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that since $f$ is differentiable, it is also continuous.

$2^{-n}$ and $3^{-n}$ both converge to zero.

Using the property you outlined above and continuity, we must have

$f(0)\geq 0$ by taking the limit of $f(2^{-n})$

Similarly, by taking the limit of $f(3^{-n})$, we must have $f(0)\leq 0$.

Thus $f(0)=0$

Notice now that since $f$ is differentiable, the following limits exist

$f'(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(2^{-n})-f(0)}{2^{-n}-0}$

$f'(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(3^{-n})-f(0)}{3^{-n}-0}$

But $\frac{f(2^{-n})}{2^{-n}}>0$ for all n, so that $f'(0)\geq 0$

and $\frac{f(3^{-n})}{3^{-n}}<0$ for all n, so that $f'(0)\leq 0$

This of course implies $f'(0)=0$

Answer (score 1):

The theorem you want to be using is that *if* a limit $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ exists *then* the limit may be calculated by sequences. That is, given any sequence $(x_n)$ which converges to $a$ (if $g$ is not continuous at $a$ you also need to ask that $x_n \ne a$ for any $n$),

$$ \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} g(x_n).$$

For your problem, you know that $f$ is differentiable, which means that $f$ is continuous, which means that the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ exists. You also have two sequences, $x_n = 2^{-n}$ and $x_n = 3^{-n}$ which converge. Therefore

$$
\begin{align*}
f(0) &= \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) \qquad \text{ (by continuity)} \\
     &= \lim_{n \to \infty} f(2^{-n}) \quad \text{(by the theorem)} \\
     &= \lim_{n \to \infty} f(3^{-n}) \quad \text{(by the theorem).} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Now you can bring in the inequalities $f(3^{-n}) < 0 < f(2^{-n})$.

Answer (score 1):

### OUTLINE

Both $\langle 2^{-n} \rangle$ and $\langle 3^{-n} \rangle$ are sequences that go to zero. So, we have $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) \ge 0$ from the first condition and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) \le 0$ from the second condition. Combine with continuity to get:
$$f(0) = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$$

Observe that $g(x) := \dfrac{f(x)}x$ is another function satisfying the two conditions. Therefore:
$$f'(0) = \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} g(h) = 0$$

---

### PROOF

For the sake of a contradiction, WLOG assume $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = L$ where $L > 0$.

Then, $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in \Bbb R: |x| < \delta \implies |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.

Now, let $\epsilon = \dfrac L2$, and the corresponding $\delta$ be $\delta_0$.

Pick $x = 3^{-\lceil -\log_3 \delta_0 \rceil}$, whose existence is guaranteed by the [Archimedean Principle](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Archimedean_Principle).

We see that $|x| = 3^{-\lceil -\log_3 \delta_0 \rceil} < 3^{\log_3 \delta_0} = \delta_0$.

However, $f(x)<0$ from the condition, which contradicts $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.